# Replace list in cell by values from other query

Tags: vlookup, powerquery

I have issue with defining smart data replacement in power query.

I am querying data from SharePoint, from multiple lists to create desired report.

If I need to replace values in column which is containing only 1 number, I am using merge queries function as "vlookup" replacement.

The issue starts when one column is containing multiple numbers, separated by semicolon.

Example
Source list:
| Unique ID | Name | Assignees_ID|
|-|-|-|
| Epic1 | Blabla1| 1 |
|Epic2 | Blabla2| 1;2;3|

"Vlookup_list" query:
|Assignees_ID|Assignees_Names|
|-|-|
|1|Mark|
|2|Irina|
|3|Bart|

Expected output:
| Unique ID | Name | Assignees_ID  |Assignees_Names |
|-|-|-| - |
| Epic1 | Blabla1| 1 | Mark|
|Epic2 | Blabla2| 1;2;3| Mark; Irina; Bart|

So is there a smart way to perform such transition? I was trying multiple possibilities but my knowledge is too low to perform it.

Kind regards
Bartosz

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In powerquery

Load the Vlookup_list into powerquery.   Name the query **VlookupNamesQuery**  File .. close and load to ... create connection only

Load the Example Source list into powerquery

Right click the Assignees_ID column and split by each semi-colon into rows

Merge in **VlookupNamesQuery** and match on ID using left outer join. Expand using arrows atop column to get Assignees_Names

Group on UniqueID and Name.  Use home ... advanced editor ... to modify code to use Text.Combine to put together the ones that were split, as per below

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ExampleSourceListRange"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"UniqueID", type text}, {"Name", type text}, {"Assignees_ID", type text}}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {{"Assignees_ID", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Assignees_ID"),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Assignees_ID", Int64.Type}}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type1",{"Assignees_ID"},VlookupNamesQuery,{"Assignees_ID"},"Names",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Names" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Names", {"Assignees_Names"}, {"Assignees_Names"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Expanded Names", {"UniqueID", "Name"}, {
    {"Assignees_ID", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([Assignees_ID], Text.From), ";"), type text},
    {"Assignees_Names", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([Assignees_Names], Text.From), ";"), type text}
})
in  #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that helped!